calculating average lifespan of client memberships without bias for older sales people
I work for a company that sells gym memberships and my employer asked me to calculate the average lifespan of client memberships without bias for older agents.
So like a sales person that's been selling memberships for 5 years can have clients that have been members for 5 years whereas a sales person that was hired two months ago clearly can't. To work around this the owner of my company suggested I calculate how long currently active members are liable to stick around and use that projected figure instead of how long those active members have currently stuck around.
The problem is that even when I do that it's still biased for older sales people and, from my vantage point, this seems like it's kinda unavoidable?
New clients are much more likely to cancel then old clients. ie. new clients are high risk clients whereas old clients are low risk clients. Old sales people will have a mix of high risk and low risk clients whereas new sales people will exclusively have high risk clients and it seems to me that that fact is gonna make older salespeople look better than newer ones through no fault of the newer sales people and it doesn't seem to me that there's much that can be done about that. Or is there?
Like maybe for the purposes of this calculation I could make certain assumptions that'd kinda eliminate this bias. One that comes to mind is that I could use company-wide probabilities that a client will pay from one month to the next (instead of sales person specific probabilities) and then assume that all active lead are the same age but, if I do that, all sales people will have the exact same average lifespan. If I used sales person specific probabilities the bias would reintroduce itself.

For a hypothetical more experienced sales person, what about their clients (in the past) who subsequently resigned their membership?  Further, for the more difficult question, what percentage of the clients of the newer sales person should be assumed to have a client membership that will endure for years?  What are the psychological/life-style attributes of a client whose membership endures, versus a client whose membership does not endure?  This entire comment's idea is that the first question posed in this comment is relevant to the subsequent questions.

If you have the data for it, you could begin by estimating the overall client risk curve: that is, the probability that a client who's had a membership for $n$ months canceling in the next month, for each value of $n$.
Then you can check if an individual agent influences the risk curve for their clients. It's still going to be true, of course, that for older agents you can answer the question, "Are their clients more likely to stick around for at least one year?" and for an agent hired two months ago, you can't. But you can answer the question, "Are their clients more likely to stick around for a second month?" for both agents.

This is the most direct way to answer the question you're asking - which agents have better retention rates - but it's not easily converted into the form of "average lifespan".
Even converting the risk curve to average lifespan is not a completely straightforward calculation. If we let $p_{n-1 \to n}$ b the probability that an $(n-1)$-month client renews their membership for the $n^{\text{th}}$ month, then we can define $p_{1 \to n}$ as $\prod_{k=2}^n p_{k-1 \to k}$: the probability that a new client lasts until the $n^{\text{th}}$ month. (By this calculation, $p_{1 \to 1} = 1$: each new client pays for a month of membership, which I'm assuming is what's going on.) Then the average lifespan is given by $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{1 \to n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=2}^n p_{k-1 \to k}.$$ Obviously you're not going to have infinite data here, but maybe it's reasonable to assume that for large $k$, $p_{k-1 \to k}$ eventually becomes constant? Or maybe another model is clearly better after looking at the data.
One thing we could do (see below for caveats) for "average lifespan of a specific agent's clients" is to replace the global average $p_{k-1 \to k}$ by that specific agent's average $\hat p_{k-1 \to k}$ in the cases where that agent has lasted $k$ months, but continue using the global average in other cases. This is not necessarily correct, but it's not clear which direction it's wrong in.

This computes an average, but we might also worry about how precise that estimate is. If the global $p_{2 \to 3}$ is $90\%$, but a particular new agent's specific $\hat p_{2\to 3}$ is based on only two clients, even if this agent is about average, this estimated probability is either $\frac12$ or $1$ (or if very unlucky, $0$). Either way, this has a drastic effect on predicted average lifespan.
What you really want to do is make a prediction for each agent's retention rates that's partially based on that agent's data and partially based on that global average, so that if we have very little data on an agent in some respect, then the global average is doing most of the work. There's a lot of further theory you could look into for how to do this, because this is fundamentally the same problem as estimating product ratings based on reviews. You don't want a product that's gotten a single review that happens to be $5$ stars to be at the top of your rankings.
Apart from that, maybe you want to ask the question of whether different salespeople actually have an effect on the risk curve, especially the tail end. If someone's been a client for five years, maybe the actual reason they cancel a membership is that they move to a different city and can't go to this gym anymore, which has nothing to do with who sold them the gym membership.
